# In interactive report 'Heading' fixed to 'Region' doesn't work with control break

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive report where I have set the 'Heading' Fixed to 'Region' and setting 'Maximum Report Height' to 800.

It works fine if the normal report is loaded. i.e. the horizontal scrollbar is fixed at this height on the screen and we do not need to go down to the bottom to scroll horizontally.

But the issue is that it doesn't work with Control breaks on the screen. If i use control break, I have to go down to the bottom of the screen and then I can see the horizontal scrollbar.

Does anybody know, how can this be resolved? How can I fix the horizontal scrollbar in case of control breaks ?

Thanks,
Abha

Comment: Has anybody faced something similar to this ? It would be really helpful if somebody could share some information regarding this issue.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue on my application by trying to set the heading fixed to region, but couldn't find the option on the interactive report. I had faced a somewhat similar problem, though regarding width. Can you give a few tips on how to reproduce it?

Comment: hi..To reproduce Please click on Interactive Report --> Attributes section on the right side of the screen. Scroll down  and there you will see section named "Heading". There we can set it to region and the report height.

Comment: I didn't manage to truly reproduce the issue because my report didn't have as many columns, but some search on the oracle forums led me to this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3812273

John Snider gives a solution, though you have to try it out and see if it truly works.